# Splitting a large libsvm formatted file with command line tools

Tags: python, command-line, sed, awk, bigdata

I have a very large libsvm formatted file (150GB) where each line is like the following:

-1 430018:1 429765:1 428103:1 428954:1 430172:1 427300:1 429485:1 432367:1 427059:1 426870:1 426556:2

(first token is label, and the others are feature:value pairs).

I wrote a program in Python to convert this into [label, [array of feature ids], [array of values]] such as:

[-1, [430018,429765,428103,...  ], [1,1,1,...] ]

but it runs extremely slow in Python (I was able to process only 10GB file in 3 hours).

Is there a way to take this file and change the format to [label, [array of feature ids], [array of values]] per line and write it to another file?

For the reference, here is the Python script I wrote to convert each line:

```
def convert(f, line)
        l = line.strip().split(" ")
        label = int(l[0])
        x = [map(int, f.split(":")) for f in l[1:]]
        x_idx, x_val = zip(*x)
        f.write(str([label, x_idx, x_val])+"\n")
```

Comment: just to confirm, if f in the params to convert just a file pointer?

Comment: Can I ask what happens to the data after this? I can't help but wonder whether something more like a dictionary e.g. with counts or sums for the values of each feature may be more useful?

Comment: @ChrisProsser actually in my original code I don't send f as parameter, I return x_idx, x_val, label back from the function and write to the file in main. I just added f to the function arguments in sake of complete code.

Comment: @ChrisProsser after that I need to perform some mathematical operations on each line based on index and value pairs. So in my code what I really need is to obtain x_idx, x_val in separate arrrays. I was doing this parsing per line while I am performing the mathematical updates but this makes my code way slower. So now I want to do this line processing/separation first and then I can read already-parsed arrays per line. I think (hope) it will be much faster :)

Comment: There is a real question here. But it needs work. Please show us the code, the real code you're using, not the code "for sake of completeness". It seems your doing the processing one line at a time, this can be accelerated a lot.

Comment: The constant file reading a writing may be slowing you down. However, unless you have a monster of a server to run this on it is much to large to do in memory. Have you considered trying building up a list of all of the lines and then just writing to the file each time you reach an increment e.g. every 10k or 100k?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -u --posix "
s/^\([^ ]*\) \{1,\}\(.*\)$/[\1,[,\2 ][/
:peer
s/,\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\):\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\) \(.*\)$/,\1,\3,\2/
t peer
s/\[,/[/g
s/,]/]/g
s/$/]/
" yourfile
```

The -u is mandatory on this kind of HUGE file. --posix is for GNU sed

-i if direct modification, if not redirect it.

I have no idea of performance on such a file. if too slow, will can still try other sed more efficient in performance but maybe harder to define.